# C# Void to List type conversion error using List.AddRange()

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, typeerror

I have two lists, which I populate and then attempt to concatenate together, but I am getting a void-to-list conversion error

```
public async Task<List<riskregister_hazard_template>> GetCategory(string _level1, string _level2)
    {

     List<riskregister_hazard_template> categories;
     List<riskregister_hazard_template> secondChunk;

     categories = await riskTable.Where(r => r.level_1 == _level1).Where(r => r.level_2 == _level2).ToListAsync();
     secondChunk = await riskTable.Skip(50).Where(r => r.level_1 == _level1).Where(r => r.level_2 == _level2).ToListAsync();


     List<riskregister_hazard_template> newList = categories.AddRange(secondChunk);

     return newList;
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)` will simply add all of the items from the parameter to the caller collection, this works in similar way that `List<T>.Add(T item)` works, you don't get anything as a return value, the collection is simply updated.

Just do it on a separate line:

```
categories.AddRange(secondChunk);
List<riskregister_hazard_template> newList = categories;
```

Or if you don't want the reference type behavior:

```
categories.AddRange(secondChunk);
List<riskregister_hazard_template> newList = new List<riskregister_hazard_template>(categories.Concat(secondChunk));
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, silly error on my part!

Comment: @BarneyChambers if this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer. I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No worries Deadzone, I had to wait for the 15 minute timer